# Find $a$ and $b$ so that $A$ is invertible.

Tags: matrices

Let:$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
  a  &0&0 & 0 &b \\
  b      &a &0 & 0 & 0 \\
     0  &b& a& 0 & 0\\
0 &0&b&a&0\\
0&0&0&b&a
\end{bmatrix}^{100}
$$

I thought this matrix would be invertible if $B=A^{1/100}$ is invertible, and found that it was invertible $\forall a\neq0$ and $a\neq-b$.

How do I justify the part: $A$ invertible $\iff B$ invertible?

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that a matrix is invertible if and only if it has nonzero determinant, and the fact that the determinant of a product of matrices is the product of the determinants. Make sure that $\det B$ is nonzero. Then $B$ is invertible. Furthermore $\det A=(\det B)^{100}$, which is zero if and only if the determinant of $A$ is zero. Since we chose $\det A\neq 0$, $\det B\neq 0$ and $B$ is invertible. You can do this without explicitly calculating the determinant. For instance, if $B$ has full rank, then you know it has nonzero determinant, even if you don't know what the determinant is.

Comment: Is there any way to prove this without the determinant (Using the rank, maybe?)? Also, wouldn't that only prove the arrow one way?

Comment: Yes to the first question, no to the second. See my additions.

Comment: I'm sorry Alex, I  meant without using any properties of the determinant, I know this may sound stupid, but in the class I'm in, we haven't studied determinants (I have, but I can't use it's properties, as they haven't been covered in class).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews gives a good proof of this below.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is invertible, then $A^{-1}=(B^{-1})^{100}$. That's easy to prove using induction on the exponent - that $(B^n)^{-1}=(B^{-1})^n$.

On the other hand, if $A$ is invertible, then $B\cdot (B^{99}A^{-1})=I$, so $B$ is invertible.